# Connecting to Database In PHP

Tags: php, mysql, windows

I am currently attempting to migrate my website from MVC asp.net to PHP after experiencing numerous issues with my host provider.  The initial changes have proved easy with PHP being quite simple to get to grips with.  However, I have hit a brick wall for the last few pages that require interaction with an SQL database.

I have worked through a number of different tutorials and helps and each one leads to the sample problem.

```
function db_connect()
{
    $conn = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', '') or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db ('Database');

    return $conn;
}
```

Which returns the error "Call to undefined function mysql_connect()" on the first line.

I have checked the php.ini file and this seems correct

```
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\Jcx.Software\VS.Php\2013\php 5.4\ext"

extension=php_mysql.dll
```

And the dll is in the corresponding directory.

I think I am probably missing something really obvious, but would appreciate any help someone can give me.

Comment: see what you have `phpinfo();`

Comment: If you are just starting to port that code you really should avoid using the old `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated mysql extension, it's been discouraged for years now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Most tutorials try to teach you very very old practice, even deprecated or removed stuff like `mysql_` functions. Google for `mysql php pdo` and you will find better stuff.

Comment: Try using PDO or mysqli* functions instead, just as a note.

Comment: "after experiencing numerous issues with my host provider" And using PHP under Windows is a realistic hosting assumption? I guess you should start using a UNIX based system to develop such things…

Comment: As you can tell from the above comments, you should **not** use mysql_ functions, as the **[manual clearly indicates](http://us1.php.net/function.mysql-connect)**. Use either **[mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** methods for your database connection. And make sure you know what **[SQL Injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** is and how to avoid it happening.

Comment: If you're migrating from MVC to PHP, you really should be using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). Writing PHP from the ground up is going to take forever and, as you've demonstrated here, you're going to do it completely wrong unless you spend some time reading a guide like [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

Comment: Thanks guys.  That's great.  Tried PDO and it's worked straight away.  That'll teach me for looking at tutorials.  lol

Answer (score 0):

use mysqli. By the way, you should create another user with set privileges and never have users log in as the root user

```
function db_connect()
{

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", $password, $database);

    if ($conn->connect_errno){
       //Error connecting
    }
}
```

Comment: PDO is significantly better than `mysqli` when it comes to binding parameters, the named placeholder feature alone is irreplaceable. If you must use `mysqli`, at least use the object-oriented interface.